# Flatten multidimensional HashMaps for better performance?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I frequently use **multidimensional HashMaps**, i.e. HashMaps containing HashMaps. On a two-key basis, for example, I set/get a stored value with

```
hashmapMulti.get(key1).put(key2,x);
hashmapMulti.get(key1).get(key2);
```

However, I could also use a "flat" hashmap and combine the two keys to set/get a value:

```
hashmapFlat.put(key1+"|"+key2,x);
hashmapFlat.get(key1+"|"+key2);
```

If I'm informed correctly, the **time complexity** for put and get should "more or less" be **O(1)** for HashMaps. With the flattening, I basically exchange the cost of a get (constant time) by the cost of combining 3 strings.

**Which way is faster?**

**Does the best choice depend in the number of objects stored in the HashMap(s)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is faster the get(key).

As you know, working with string (especially concatenating) is, performance wise, EVIL, as, in the end, concatenating string is:
- create a new object String
- loop (cost: O(n)) on first string
- loop (cost: O(n)) on second string

(and in your example, you do that 2x: 1 for get, 1 for put)

If the multidimensional hashmap fit in your design and represent correctly what are you modelling, I don't see any drawback in using it.

If you have a large number of object, the choiche of a two dimensional HashMap may add a little overhead to your memory footprint, but as I don't know your costraint (# of object and memory available) I can't say if you need to go for the flattening

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. As I use the multidimensional HashMaps in various projects, the number of contained objects can strongly vary. Usually they contain something like 10*1000 to 10*100000 entries. As long as the memory overhead is in the range of a few percent, it doesn't matter in my applications.

Answer (score 5):

A third option is to write a class that encapsulates the composite key.

It will have two fields for the two individual keys and if you override its `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods correctly, you won't have to depend on string concatenation.

Although performance-wise your best option is to write actual benchmarks and compare your implementations, this is definitely the cleanest solution: it's instantly readable and it avoids the rather brittle dependency on string concatenation (i.e. you can have keys that contain the `|` character).

Comment: I'm absolutely no Java expert, so please excuse this dumb follow up question: Let's say I create for example a class "KeyPair" that does what you suggest, wouldn't I have the additional cost of instantiating a key, plus an additional equality check for the second key in the equals() method? If I understood you correctly, you meant to use it like **hashmapFlat.get(newKeyPair(key1,key2))**, right?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, you may have to create a new `KeyPair` every time (although depending on the actual use case you may not have to) but you should compare it with the cost of string concatenation: creating a new `StringBuilder` object, complete with its own character buffer, then copying three strings into that buffer (potentially extending the buffer), then copying the result into a newly created `String` object. In a `HashMap` lookup `equals()` will only be invoked if there is a hash collision, in every other case only `hashCode()` is used and there's no real extra cost there.

Comment: That said, unless you have benchmarks that prove that this is a performance bottleneck, you really shouldn't tweak your code for hopeful performance benefits.

Comment: You also have the added benefit of Type Safety. Needing to look up a value by `String` tells you nothing about the format of that string. Need to look it by `KeyPair`, much easier to remember what you need to supply. And the compiler will complain if you don't give it the correct input.

Answer (score 2):

> Which way is faster?

You would need to profile. I would rather do one look up by default (using [biziclop's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940479/360211) where I have more than one key) and I would only consider otherwise if there was a proven performance problem.

> Does the best choice depend in the number of objects stored in the HashMap(s)?

Yes, but you can manage it so that one is as good as two for any number of objects:

HashMaps have a number of buckets. The hash value from the key, a 32 bit value is mapped to a much smaller range to select the bucket. This means that objects with different hashes can share buckets. When objects share buckets, performance falls as a linear search of the bucket takes place.

Worse case is a hash function that returns a constant number causing all keys to map to a single bucket, and best case is one that leads to an even distribution of key value pairs in buckets.

The number of buckets (HashMaps capacity) can be increased which combined with a good hash function can minimise the sharing of buckets.

Read this and pay attention to the advice on getting the capacity right: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. I never really thought about modifying the initial capacity or load factor, mainly because I only know about the absolute basics of HashTables, Buckets, Hashing etc. I'll pay more attention to that in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

> Which way is faster?

You need to benchmark it ... using a benchmark that closely mirrors what your real application will be doing.  Your actual application running with real data would be the ideal benchmark.

The problem is that the problem has too many variables for a simple analysis to be plausible.  Consider:

- If you use two layers of nested maps, then each lookup involves two sets of hash calculations, array probes, and hash chain searches.
- But on the flip side, using a combined key most likely will entail doing a string concatenation each time you want to do a lookup.  In addition, if we assume that key strings used for the lookups are temporary, the String classes `hashcode` caching won't be effective.

Then there are the variables:

- the ratio of lookups to other operations,
- the total number of entries,
- the number, and average lengths of the component key strings,
- the degree to which the component (or combined) key strings are shared / reused,
- the memory usage patterns of other parts of the application, and so on.

Finally there is the difficulty of *apriori* modelling of second order effects such the performance effects of memory caches, virtual memory and the garbage collector in the context of the application.

---

My advice would be to implement your complete application using one of the strategies, and then benchmark it (with real data) and profile it:

- If benchmarking and profiling conclusively show that this part of your application is performance critical, then create a second version of the application using the alternative strategy.
- Finally benchmark and profile the second version, and decide which one gives the best performance.